# HTML Image not reduce size while zoom out/in, It's not responsive in Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I've navigation bar and then below that an image and some divs text. When zooming in/out the entire website, it will not reduce the size of the image. How can I keep the image and image text also responsive while zooming in or out.

**Image Section**

```
<section>
  <img src="images/cover.jpg" style="width: 100%;" >
  <div class="row img-heading">
     <h1>Five Star Homes</h1>
  </div>
</section>
```

**Image Css**

```
.img-heading{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Comment: did you tried `image-reponsive` class in your image??

Comment: use class="img-responsive"

Comment: I already used class="img-responsive" and img-fluid actually when i zoom in/out the image size will be same not reduce.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle for better understanding  ?

Comment: can you reproduce your issue in fiddle/snippet??

Answer (score 0):

in bootstrap 4, you can put `img-fluid` class to your image, while in old bootstrap you use `img-responsive`